# Display Bootstrap Tooltip based on responsive layout

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm having some trouble integrating Bootstrap Tooltips to `button` elements on touch devices. Using the following code, on a desktop layout, when I hover over the button, it'll correctly show the tooltip. If I click the button, it calls the JavaScript linked to the button (or a href link). However, on touch devices, since there's no hover action, the tooltip gets called first when I click the button and I'll have to click it again to call the action. How do I fix this?

```
<button class="btn btn-mini btn-want" data-title="Buy" data-url="/buy/c66860de7d6d10000035" rel="tooltip" data-original-title="">
            <i class="icon-plus"></i>
          </button>
```

One idea I had was to use the responsive classes in Bootstrap: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive

The classes I think can work are: `.visible-desktop` and `.hidden-desktop`

Is this the right approach? If so, how do I implement Tooltips for desktop layouts but disable it for non-desktops layouts?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Modernizr.touch](http://modernizr.com/docs/) to detect touch-enabled clients - and for those clients disable the tooltip plugin.